# android set menu icon from base adapter

Tags: android, adapter, radix

i have an android app with a custom list view.
to put data in this list view, i use a base adapter.

in my base adapter i have an OnCheckedChangeListener.
every time i checked / unchecked a checkbox of my list view, i count +1 / -1 the pref "DeleteCheckboxesCount"

but i would like to hide an menu item from my base adapter, if "DeleteCheckboxesCount" == 0

how can i get access from base adapter to the menu icon of my custom list view class (Main.class)

```
SelectCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (SelectCheckBox.isChecked() == true) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("DeleteCheckboxesCount", prefs.getInt("DeleteCheckboxesCount", 0) + 1);
                    editor.commit();

                } else {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("DeleteCheckboxesCount", prefs.getInt("DeleteCheckboxesCount", 0) - 1);
                    editor.commit();

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to pass in the `Activity` in your adapter's constructor, and then call `Activity::invalidateOptionsMenu`.

You could then create a `getDeleteCheckboxCount` method in your adapter that you check inside of your activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Something like this in your Activity:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter( this, ... );
```

And then:

```
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(...) {
if ( mAdapter.getDeleteCheckboxCount > 0 ) { 
   ... 
} else {
   ...
}
```

And call `mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu()` in your `OnCheckedChangedListener`.